# find a Möbius transformation between the unit disc to $\{|\operatorname{im}(z)|<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

find a Möbius transformation between the unit disc to $\bigl\{|\operatorname{im}(z)|<1\bigr\}$ that satisfies: $f(0)=0,\; |f'(0|)>0$.
My try: I tried to plug all this condition and got:
$\frac{ax}{cx+d}$ and that a and d must have the same sign, but nothing else.

Comment: Did you mean that $a$ and $d$ have the same sign?

Comment: @Cuhrazatee yes

Comment: Generally it has the form $w=\frac{kz-e^{i\theta}(2-k)}{z-e^{i\theta}}$. And $w=\frac{2z}{z+1}$ fits.

Comment: Möbius transformations map disks to disks or halfplanes, therefore no such Möbius transformation exists.